# Horizontal Scroll/Overflow issue on mobile devices

Tags: wordpress, overflow, horizontal-scrolling

This website: occecvision.org is having horizontal scrolling/ blank white space on either side of the content on my phone (iPhone, haven't checked Android).

I've already tried body, html {overflow-x:hidden !important;max-width:100% !important} but that didn't work.

I assume some image or element is larger than the device width but I can't see anything breaking the layout when I look through the page elements.

I'm using Bricks Builder with Wordpress if that makes a difference.

Please help me diagnose this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the website in desktop (Firefox) and mobile (Safari) and can't replicate the problem. A simple overflow hidden on the html element should do it.

```
html{
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```